# Saving state of screen A when navigating from screen A to screen B and than back to screen A with Android Navigation

Tags: android, android-navigation-graph

I am trying to understand Android Navigation. I am using androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.0
Suppose I have to screens, screen A and Screen B. And say screen A has some sort of state e.g. a counter. How do i progamm it so that when i navigate from screen A to Screen B and back that the counter of screen A shows the same value it had shown when navigating from A to B?

I thought that as long as I had not popped the screen from the navigation back stack its state would be preserved, what am i getting wrong?

For example this nav graph:

```
fun Navigation(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screens.Screen1.title) {
        composable(route = Screens.Screen1.title) {
            val viewModel = ScreenViewModel()
            Screen1(viewModel, count = 
            viewModel.count.collectAsState())
        }
        composable(route = Screens.Screen2.title) {
            Screen2(
                onButtonClick = { navController.navigateUp() }
            )
        }
    }

}
```

with these two composables as nav destinations:

```
 @Composable
    fun Screen1(viewModel: ScreenViewModel, count: State<Int>) {
        Column {
            Button(onClick = {viewModel.onButtonPressed()}) {
                Text("Counter")
            }
            Text(count.value.toString())
        }
    
    }
    
    @Composable
    fun Screen2(onButtonClick: () -> Unit) {
        Column {
            Button(onClick = onButtonClick) {
                Text(text = "get back")
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us your code for screen A?

Comment: What is a screen? I know activity. I know fragment. But what is a screen?

Comment: @ianhanniballake added my code to the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [ViewModel in Compose guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#viewmodel), you **must** use the `viewModel()` method to get an instance of your ViewModel:

```
val viewModel = viewModel<ScreenViewModel>()
```

Using that method is what actually stores the ViewModel and ensures that you always get the same instance back. When you just call the constructor as part of composition, you will get a new instance each time, this losing any state in that ViewModel.